# Add class to a class and anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass

I want to add a class to an anchor tag using jQuery. The anchor tag is inside a list item with the class nav-1. I tried the following with no luck.

```
$( ".nav-1 a" ).addClass( "pink" );
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

As far as I can see there in no error for this in the Script tab on Firebug. There is no class of pink being added. The JS file is in the head so maybe this is problem. I will test and post my results.

The page can be found here: http://cqwebdesign.co.uk/partybits2008.co.uk

I added the jQuery code the the script.js file its the last load external JS file in the head, and I added the following code just before the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".nav-1 a" ).addClass( "pink" );
    });
</script>
```

Still no luck with the class being added.

I believe it might be the way jQuery is included in the software. It uses Prototype but the framework I'm using integrates jQuery and adds noconflict feature I think.

Comment: Try this `$( "li.nav-1>a" ).addClass( "pink" );`

Comment: @Amit: that makes no significant difference, it's just more strict about *where* the `<a>` occurs. What errors/problems are you getting? Any errors reported in your JavaScript Console ('F12' in most browsers)? Can you show your HTML, because if it really is as you describe it, then that jQuery should work (assuming you've correctly included jQuery).

Comment: where are you inserting this piece of code? if its in the head, then the dom is still not loaded(the anchors dont exist yet). It also depends when you want the code to execute.

Comment: Please include some additional details in your post such as if jQuery is included, if so where jQuery is included (head or body), is the code wrapped in a DOM ready handler, where is this code located (head or body), are there any errors in your console, the layout of your HTML, etc. It's much too vague at this point for us to provide any reasonable explanations other than pure speculations of what might be wrong.

Comment: Updated my post. I think it might be that the JS file is being loaded in the head. Could I use jQuery(document).ready(function($) { in the an external file? I am still leaning JS/Jquery.

Comment: You "believe it might be the way jQuery is included in the software" - I suspect you are right. It doesn't look like jQuery is included at all to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends when you want the class added, on what event.

Here it is on click http://jsfiddle.net/33dntdtx/

```
$('.add').on('click', function(e){
    $( ".nav-1 a" ).addClass( "pink" );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But you can add the class on every event, basically there is nothing wrong with your code :)

You should fire your code when the DOM is ready to be manipulated.
In jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".nav-1 a" ).addClass( "pink" );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem above by changing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".nav-1 a" ).addClass( "pink" );
    });
</script>
```

To :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $( ".nav-1 a" ).addClass( "pink" );
    });
</script>
```